# NodeJS String Replace performance - newlines inside of many sets of xml tags

Tags: node.js, regex, string

I have a very large string that I'm running a replace loop on. The length of the string is `15967025` characters (yes its large). Loop taking 4-5 seconds for each iteration on large string.

I'm looping through the string with a while loop and replacing it with a pretty complex regex - the end goal to replace all newline characters inside of matching `text:p` tags with `<text:line-break/>`:

```
const undefinds = /(undefined)/g;
const nulls = /(<[A-z:\s-="\d]*>)(null)(<\/[A-z:\s-="\d]*>)/gi;
const nullsReplace = '$1None$3';

const regexToReplace = /(<text:p ....>)(...\n...)(</text:p>)/g;
const replaceWith = '$1<text:line-break/>$2';

export function cleanOutput(output) {

    while (output.match(regexToReplace)) {
        output = output.replace(regexToReplace, replaceWith);
    }

    return output;
}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that with every time this loop runs it takes about 4-5 seconds. Is this normal with this size of string? Is there a better way to do this?

** Edit 1: **

I'm adding a more detailed example for the patterns to replace. I don't think I can use the `/g` flag since I'm doing multiple replacements within some matching tags.

Here's the full example of what I'm doing, the goal is replace newline characters in the `<text:p>` elements with `<text:line-break />`. But I want to preserve the wrapping text which is xml.

```js
const newLines = /(<text:p[^/>]*?>[\s\S]*?)(\r\n|\r|\n)+?([\s\S]*?<\/text:p>)/g;
const newLineReplace = '$1<text:line-break/>$3';

export function cleanOutput(output) {
    output = output.replace(undefinds, 'None')
        .replace(nulls, nullsReplace);

    while (output.match(newLines)) {
        output = output.replace(newLines, newLineReplace);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Edit 2:

I added the missing undefineds/nulls replace. Sorry for not including that. The slowness definitely occurs in the while loop though - it does take about 4-5 seconds between each iteration.

Edit 3:

Here's a sample test case to try:

```
<text:p>some text\n\nother text\n</text:p>
```

expected output:

```
<text:p>some text<text:line-break/><text:line-break/>other text<text:line-break/></text:p>
```

Comment: why are you replacing in loop? Any specific reason for this? I you just call replace once.

Comment: 1) Just use `function cleanOutput(output) { return output.replace(regexToReplace, replaceWith); }`, 2) `stuff to save` must be optimized as much as possible, you need to add the actual pattern you are using.

Comment: I guess I'm using the loop since there may be more than once instance of  `stuff to replace` inside each match.

Comment: `.replace` together with a regex having `g` flag replaces all occurrences.

Comment: If you need more help and make your question answerable, please add more details about the patterns you use.

Comment: It is not clear what you have in `output.replace(undefinds, 'None').replace(nulls, nullsReplace);`, it might be also the cause of slow code execution. If you want to replace all line breaks in between `<text:p>` tag, you could use ``.replace(/(<text:p[^/>]*>)([^<]*<\/text:p>)/g, (m, x,y) =>  `${x}${y.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '<text:line-break/>')}`)``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks for the response - here's a sample test case where that doesn't work correctly:
`<text:p>some text\n\nother text\n</text:p>`

Comment: I thought it was ok to replace multiple line breaks with one tag. If it is not what you want, use ``s.replace(/(<text:p[^/>]*>)([^<]*<\/text:p>)/g, (m, x,y) =>  `${x}${y.replace(/\r\n?|\n/g, '<text:line-break/>')}`)``

Comment: I see what you mean now. I'm going to try this out right now, thanks! I think this is very close if not exactly what I need. I'll follow up in a few minutes

Comment: Okay - I have a working solution - using your helpful logic there @WiktorStribiżew. It ended up being a little more complicated than what you had but the concept is the same, and I am hoping this is going to resolve the slow replacement loop. Thanks!
https://pastebin.com/b84zuhWp

Comment: `/(<text:p[^\/>]*?>)((?:.*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)+.*)+)(<\/text:p[^\/>]*?>)/g` is truly bad and will slow down the code a lot. Do not use it. Use `/(<text:p(?:\s[^\/>]*)?>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/text:p>)/g`. Although it will also be a bit slow, but I have too little data to go on improving it. Note closing tags cannot have attributes, `<\/text:p>` is enough (no need using `<\/text:p[^\/>]*?>`).

Comment: I know its bad :p Regex is NOT my strong suit. They turn into monsters. Thank you for your advice. Your code works too - however, it will match ALL text:p, not just the ones with `\n` I believe. BUT I'm assuming the performance gains from the improvements in your regex is better than the extra iterations in searching the extra `text:p`'s.

Comment: There is quite a chance you overmatch across several `text:p` tags when using your pattern. This can be really greatly improved if we knew if there are any other (nested) tags between `<text:p>` and `</text:p>`

Comment: Yes - there could be nested tags inside the `text:p` element.

Comment: Then, it cannot be improved much more than posted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the regex point of view, it is more maintainable to match all substrings between two strings, and later replace all occurrences of some other pattern inside the matches only rather than trying to figure out a universal pattern that will find all occurrences of a pattern between two strings.

So, you need to match all substrings between `<text:p>` and `</text:p>` and replace all occurrences of line breaks (let's define a line break as a CR, LF or CRLF char sequences):

```js
let text = `<text:p>some text\n\nother text\n</text:p>`;
const regex = /(<text:p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/text:p>)[^<]*)*)(<\/text:p>)/g;
text = text.replace(regex, (_, open, content, close) =>
  `${open}${content.replace(/\r\n?|\n/g, '<text:line-break/>')}${close}`);
console.log(text);
```

Note `(<text:p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)([^<]*(?:<(?!\/text:p>)[^<]*)*)(<\/text:p>)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAdRFx/1)) is an unrolled (=more efficient) `(<text:p(?:\s[^>]*)?>)([\w\W]*?)(<\/text:p>)` pattern ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAdRFx/2)), that simply matches `<text:p...>` tag and then any text up to the first occurrence of `</text:p>`.

The `\r\n?|\n` pattern matches a CRLF or CR pattern with `\r\n?` and an LF ending with `\n`.

Comment: Thank you - this has been a huge help!

Comment: Done! I improved the title a bit too - so maybe this will be useful to others in the future. its kind of specific use case.